# How to fetch upto documents that having a subcollection in it

Tags: java, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image of database][1]I have a firebase collection starting from User collection , sub collection chats, then messages.

```
_firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection('chats')
        .doc(widget.user['id'])
        .collection('messages')
        .add({
      'text': _messageController.text,
      'sender': _auth.currentUser!.email,
      'Date': DateTime.now(),
    });
```

but when i try to list the chatlist for the user snapshot is empty list

StreamBuilder(
stream: _firestore
.collection('users')
.doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid)
.collection('chats')
.doc(widget.user['id'])
.collection('messages')
.orderBy('Date')
.snapshots(),
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
if (snapshot.hasData) {

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z1OT.png)




building a chat application and i need to list all chat that the user chats with.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrA3T.png
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get.

Comment: @AlexMamo https://freeimage.host/i/HJ0rs7n  link for firebase structure image. The chat collection contains the documents of the users that chatting with and inside that the subcollection of messages from the user.I need the documents of the chat collection to display it as list of users that the person chatting.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right document IDs in your reference?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes ...but in the case iam calling chat collection.snapshots to get document ids the chat collection contains sub collection called messages where all messages with that particular person exist. cant we get snapshot of a collection that having only a sub collection?

Comment: To understand better, do you want to read the content of a document together with all documents from the sub-collection in one go?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes. but I did it using another way. thankyou..@alexmamo